# Handling fixed position in relation to touch devices

Tags: scroll, touch, modernizr

The menu is fixed and will follow on scroll. This does not work well with touch devices.

I want to call the script, using Modernizr, when it detect no-touch devises. But I'm unsure how to do this.

Also, is there elements from the Modernizr download-page that I need to accomplish this?

Here is my script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(window).scroll(function() {

   var header = $('#fixed-bar').outerHeight(true);
   console.log(header);
   var scrollTopVal = $(this).scrollTop();
    if ( scrollTopVal > header ) {
        $('nav').css({'position':'fixed','top' :'0px', 'border-bottom':'4px solid #ff5454'});
    } else {
        $('nav').css({'position':'absolute','top':'90px', 'border-bottom':'none'});
    }
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> But I'm unsure how to do this.

You don't want to just use javascript, you want to use mostly css, and just toggle classes with javascript. Its more performant (which is super important with something like scroll loops).

```
#fixed-bar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  border-bottom:4px solid #ff5454;
}

.touch #fixed-bar, #fixed-bar.at-top {
    top: 90px;
    border-bottom: none
}
```

also, [you don't want to directly attach to window.scroll](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/animations/). Instead, you want to use requestAnimationFrame (shimming where needed) to get the most buttery smooth animations possible. [Here is a coffeescript example for jQUery](https://gist.github.com/lifedraft/7655319).With that, you would be looking to do something like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   // the height doesn't change, so we don't need to look it up on scroll.
   var headerHeight = $('#fixed-bar').outerHeight(true);

   $.request_scroll(function() {
   var scrollTopVal = $(this).scrollTop();
    if ( scrollTopVal > headerHeight ) {
        $('nav').addClass('at-top');
    }
    else {
        $('nav').removeClass('at-top');
    }
});
```

> Also, is there elements from the Modernizr download-page that I need to accomplish this?

just the `Modernizr.touch` test.

Be warned, this doesn't detect touch screens, just devices that support touchevents. That means new windows 8 laptops will be detected as `.touch`, and windows phones will not (they use pointer-events, not touch events).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It now functions as it should on mobile devices. But only because of Modernizr with touch-event.

On tablets/pc the nav follows on scroll, but with top: 90px across stationary and tablets. 

I couldn't make your css work, so I used the old script, without window.scroll function - without this, the nav will persist in keeping 90px from the top, when scrolling, instead of the 0px you saw when you first checked out my website.

I thought js. would override css settings, but it doesn't. I don't really know how to proceed.

Comment: if the css wasn't working, make sure that you are including cssclasses with the modernizr build. it is a huge perf hit to be reassigning css on scroll.

Comment: if it is not working - post a code demo using codepen or jsfiddle

Comment: I've been looking over the code and found a flaw in namegivings. #fixed-bar is not the fixed element. nav is. In this fiddle [http://jsfiddle.net/dbByU/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/dbByU/1/) I have changed the names. Hope it clear up something.

Comment: Use this fiddle: [http://jsfiddle.net/rr_kwr/rp5MV/](http://jsfiddle.net/rr_kwr/rp5MV/)

Answer (score 0):

I now have a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rr_kwr/rp5MV/) with help from Patricks answers, but as you can see, the bar does still not go to the top, when you scroll as it should, like on my [website](http://rubinreklame.dk).

Is there a solution for this? Tablets and phones don't like effects, which have $(window).scroll(function().

Currently I have this javascript on my website (the id's are different):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(window).scroll(function() {

var header = $('#fixed-bar').outerHeight(true);
   console.log(header);
//this will calculate header's full height, with borders, margins, paddings
   var scrollTopVal = $(this).scrollTop();
    if ( scrollTopVal > header ) {
        $('nav').css({'position':'fixed','top' :'0px', 'border-bottom':'4px solid #ff5454'});
    } else {
        $('nav').css({'position':'absolute','top':'90px', 'border-bottom':'none'});
    }
});
});
```

While most tablets have problems with $(window).scroll(function(), it works on desktop pc. Not much consolation though.

Is there an alternate way of getting this to work? Using touch- and pointer events, maybe someone has a working fiddle og example?